# Como enviar un array html por ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, laravel

Tengo el siguiente array html:

```
@foreach($lab->categoria as $cat)
    <label style="color:#000;margin-top:0px; margin-botton:0px"  data-nombre="{{$cat->nombre}}"><i class="fa fa-mars"></i> {{$cat->nombre}} <input value="{{$cat->id}}" name="categorialab_id[]" type="checkbox" ></label>
@endforeach
```

Que deseo enviar via ajax para procesarlos con php(laravel), en caso de que no sea ajax en el controlador bastaria hacer:

```
$array=$request->categorialab_id;
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
   $new=new Estudioslab();
   $new->estudioslab_id=$dato->id;
   $new->categorialab_id=$array[$i];
   $new->save();
}
```

el caso es que al querer enviar via ajax este no me deja y me sale el error de:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
>       at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at jt (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.w.param (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLFormElement. (2:3232)
>       at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

mi ajax es el siguiente:

```
$("#subirlaboratorio").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#btn-save-laboratorio").attr("disabled",true);
    var formData = new FormData($("#subirlaboratorio")[0]);

    $bool=confirm("Seguro de Solicitar los examenes de laboratorio?");
    if($bool){
        $.ajax({
            url:url_global+"/crearlabestudio",
            type:'get',
            data:formData,
            success:function(data){
                if(data.resp==200){

                    toastr.success(data.msn);
                    window.open(url_global+'/printlaboratorio/'+data.dato.id+'/'+paciente_id,"Imprimir","menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
                }else{
                    toastr.error(data.msn);
                }
            },
            error:function(data){  
                toastr.error(data.msn);
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El error no es realmente el array html, lo que ocurre es que jQuery intenta convertir el objeto FormData a un string, lo cual normalmente se soluciona poniendo en false estos parámetros en la solicitud ajax de jQuery:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false
```